# Which is the correct way to use schema multiple areaServed

Tags: html, schema

Which is the correct way to use schema multiple areaServed

Can anybody clear this confusion.

```html
<p class="section-text wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="0.5s" data-wow-delay="0.3s" itemprop="areaServed" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/State">
</p>
<ul id="cities-list">
  <li><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>Atlanta</li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>Fery</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: http://schema.org/Service

Comment: @mplungjan can you fix my code?

Comment: Nope. Tried to make a [mcve] that you should have fone from the start